# Adobe Acrobat Active x pro Javascript from external application

Tags: javascript, acrobat

I want to Run Acrobat Active X pro javascript from external application 
how to do that.

suppose i am inserting some pages in file1.pdf from file2.pdf using adobe javascript,
now i want to pass the file1.pdf,file2.pdf path as a variable from other application how to do that.

or

how can I use adobe javascript in .net application say vb.net or c#.net or asp.net